# Internal Server Error on Terraform provisioned API Gateway Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform to allocate a Lambda function that's triggered by a request to an API Gateway on AWS. Here's my .tf file:

```
dsf
```

This correctly sets up the Lambda function, but something is off with the API Gateway. When I curl with the output URL (https://cqsso4fw67.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com), it gives me the following:

```
curl https://cqsso4fw67.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
{"message":"Internal Server Error"}%
```

If I manually remove this API Gateway and create a new one from the AWS Console within the Lambda function and run curl again, I get "SUCCESS!" (which is what my Lambda *should* do).

```
smf
```

Any ideas how I can fix the .tf file to correctly setup the API Gateway trigger?

Here are the differences between the one created in AWS and the one provisioned in Terraform. Terraform one is at the top.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The TF code that you showed is **correct**. Most likely reason for the failure is your lambda function, which you haven't showed. You have to inspect [lambda function logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html) in CloudWatch to check why it fails.

Edit:

The function should return:

```
    return {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        'statusCode': 200,                                                                                                                                                                                    
        'body': 'SUCCESS'                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }
```

Comment: All my Lambda function does is: 
`def lambda_handler(event, context):
 return "SUCCESS!"`
This works when I manually set an API Gateway trigger, just doesn’t work with the Terraform provisioned one.

Comment: Logs only seem to return `REPORT RequestId: b21ea7ca-4ba5-4267-adc4-10e4b023718c Duration: 0.75 ms Billed Duration: 1 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 59 MB`. I know the Lambda is working because visiting https://bfye61hh6l.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/w-scan-terraform gives the SUCCESS message with an API set up within AWS. The Terraform one fails though and the logs don't provide any context oddly.

Comment: @flowermia Sadly, I don't know what you did using AWS console as you haven't showed it. Whatever you did is different then your TF code. My answer is only based on what you post in SO, and your function must return what I wrote.

Comment: I've attached an image of the differences between the two API gateways to this original post. The top one is the one provisioned by Terraform and the bottom is the default one created within AWS.

Comment: @flowermia Sadly the screenshot does not explain much. Many details are missing, such as integrations. But your question is not about how to duplicate some console created API (this should be separate question), but about your TF code. I explained you why your code does not work, and its due to lambda function's return value.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this issue, I managed to fix it by greatly simplifying things. I switched out all the API Gateway clauses in the Terraform file with just:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "apigw-terraform" {
    name          = "terraform-api"
    protocol_type = "HTTP"
    target        = aws_lambda_function.w-scan-terraform.arn
}
```

The tutorial I was following had implemented something more complex than what I needed.